# I am getting an error when issuing commands to my custom python command prompt

Tags: python, regex, class, exception

Since I don't know where the problem originates, I shall post all the code (not much). It is a value error:

This is my main.py

```
from cmdClass import *
import re
import os

mainObject = Cmd()
while True:
    try:
        userInput = str(input(f"${mainObject.getAccount()}: "))
        matches = re.search(r'^^(create|open|kill|exit) -(?:\s+([^\s]+))?$', userInput)
        if matches != True:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            command = matches.group(1)
            if matches.group(2) != None:
                parameter = matches.group(2)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        mainObject.programExit(f"Your parameter (file-name) was invalid")
    except ValueError:
        mainObject.programExit(f"Your input was invalid")
    except TypeError:
        mainObject.programExit(f"You passed unwanted arguments")
    
    if command == "create":
        try:
            mainObject.create(parameter)
        except NameError:
            mainObject.programExit("No argument was passed")
    elif command == "kill":
        try:
            mainObject.kill(parameter)
        except NameError:
            mainObject.programExit("No argument was passed")
    elif command == "open":
        try:
            mainObject.fileOpen(parameter)
        except NameError:
            mainObject.programExit("No argument was passed")
    elif command == "exit":
        mainObject.programExit()
```

This is my class in a different file

```
import os

class Cmd:
    def __init__(self):
        self.account = input("Account Name: ")
    def create(self, fileName):
        file = open(f"{self.account}_{fileName}", 'x')
    def programExit(self, exitMessage=None):
        exit(exitMessage)
    def kill(self, fileName):
        os.remove(fileName)
    def fileOpen(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, 'a+') as file:
            for i in file.readlines():
                print(i)
            lineNum = 0
            while True:
                lineNum += 1
                line = input(f"{lineNum} ")
                if line != "q\?":
                    file.write(line)
                else:
                    break
    def getAccount(self):
        return self.account
```

There may well be a problem with the regex so please look it over.

Here is a screenshot of what happens:
[image: Screenshot of code running]

It creates a value error (pretty sure its self raised but shouldn't happen in this situation). Please do not rewrite the code unless there's a major issue; I want to fix this on my own.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/bCS8aM/1

Answer (score 2):

`re.search` doesn't return a `bool`.  It returns either `None` or a match object.  The return value will never equal `True`.  Change the the following:

```
if matches != True:
    raise ValueError
```

to:

```
if matches is None:
    raise ValueError
```

Update:  The regular expression is also incorrect.  Here's a version that should work as intended:

```
matches = re.search(r'^(create|open|kill|exit)(?:\s+-([^\s]+))?$', userInput)
```

Having more than one `^` at the start is unnecessary.  A single `^` is all that's needed to anchor the search to the start of the string.  The other problem was the way the optional second group was specified.  The original regular expression had a mandatory space (which prevents "exit" from working), followed by an optional argument that begins with a `-` followed by one or more embedded spaces.  Any spaces need to occur before the `-`.  The above corrects these problems.

As an aside, the `-` doesn't seem to serve much purpose in these examples.  You could easily eliminate it if desired, but perhaps the intent is to later extend this to allow for options that are preceded by a `-`?

Comment: Though `matches` itself will not be `True` or `False`, one can cast it to such via `bool(matches)` or in this case even `if not matches: raise ValueError`

Comment: I'm sure you know that, just pointing it out for future readers.

Comment: Although you are right and I have fixed the error, it still raises the value error. If you can, please proofread my regex (I only know basic regex so a lot of this was constructed through stuff online). Thank you @JonSG and especially Tom Karzes.

Comment: @Sam64710 I updated the answer to included a corrected regular expression, along with an explanation.

Comment: Yes however it only works for the create command, not for the others. Also, when naming files in the create command, instead of 'Sam_hello.txt', it becomes 'Sam_ -hello.txt'. But thank you nonetheless.

Comment: @Sam64710 Oops, sorry, I had temporarily removed the `?:` from the outer grouping, and forgot to put it back in.  It doesn't affect what it matches, but it does affect the groupings.  I've edited it to put it back in.  Also, it behaves exactly the same for all commands.  It never behaved differently for create vs. the others (at least as far as the regular expression is concerned).  Try updating your code with what's there now.  The ` -` will no longer appear in group 2.

Comment: Thank you so much! The only issue left is that (in cmdClass.py open method) when using the open command, it doesn't actually display the contents of the file like its supposed to and instead just asks the user to add new lines. 

Also, although you probably won't contribute, here's a link to the github of this project: https://github.com/Samarth-M123/Simple_Text_Editor

Comment: @Sam64710 That sounds like a different question.  This question was about getting your regular expression to work.  This answer solves that problem.  If there are unrelated problems, it would be better to create a new question, along with your updated code.